# How can I convert large number of EPS files to PNG with a desired sizing?

Tags: png, jsx, adobe-illustrator, eps

I have bulk images in EPS having varied dimensions, all stored in a one folder.

How can I convert them all to PNG having a fixed dimension of 4500x5400 and make them store in another folder?

Can this process be done in one go, instead of manually doing it for each image?

Comment: Are the EPS files all of the same size? and do they match the size you wish to have for the PNG's? Were they generated in Illustrator or another software?

Comment: No, the EPS files are all different sizes. Yeah they were generated using illustrator.